# Automate Linux server login with 2 users using terminal in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I need to authenticate with two users on a Linux server using the following users:

1. user1
2. root

I could automate with user1 using a tool named - sshpass. Post which the terminal just **looses the communication with the local machine** and hence ignores the commands which comes after. My shell script is as follows:

```
sshpass -p my_password ssh user1@my_domain_name
spawn su
root_password
```

How to make the above script to automate the input of root password as well. ?

The tools like *Tera_Term*  and *MTputty* works great in windows but what in Ubuntu (14.04) ?

Comment: The Windows tools you mentioned work on multiple tabs. Why don't you use multiple tabs or multiple terminal instances on Linux/Ubuntu as well?

Comment: I am in need of the shell script which could log me in to a remote server followed by inputing the root password aswell so that my terminal will be ready to accept further commands.  With the script mentioned in the question, I couldn't achieve to input "su" followed by the root password..!